# Which Should I Use RandomForest Classifier or Regressor regarding the boston housing prices dataset

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

if values of my prediction column ranges from 5-50 in a particular question.
         so should i use RandomForestRegressor or RandomForestClassifier.

this question is related to boston house pricing.
Prediction Column --> (MEDV-Median value of owner-occupied homes in $1000's)

also i have read somewhere that if the predicting values are known we should use Classifier, otherwise Regressor.

Comment: housing prices are continuous values, so it can't be predicted using a classifier.

Comment: Examples in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_regression.html#gradient-boosting-regression) can easily give you a hint if you feel lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your prediction column has continuous values, hence it is regression problem.

You can use Linear regression model.

A quick answer to your question is ***RandomForestRegressor***

You can refer the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html)